# Forget Wifi Network without admin

Tags: macos, network, internet

My school MBA M1 does not have very many permissions, how would I be able to completely forget a network without an admin password? I accidentally connected to a random insecure network and now it prioritizes that instead of the Schools wifi (BTW my school's wifi is APS)[image: WHAT IT SHOWS]

Comment: If you don't have permission to unlock the panel, you will need to ask someone who does - ie, the school.

Comment: I’ve asked them and all they’ve said  is that they would need to completely reset my laptop to forget it, and I do not want that